# Create Bootstrap Dropdown Button from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I need help creating an html button from javascript using the bootstrap class and customization.

I have created a bootstrap button

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" id="testbtn" onclick="javascript('ActionTxT1' , 'dropdownMenuButton', 'btn btn-success')">Action</a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" id="testbtn" onclick="javascript('ActionTxT2' , 'dropdownMenuButton', 'btn btn-warning')">Another action</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" id="testbtn" onclick="javascript('ActionTxT3' , 'dropdownMenuButton', 'btn btn-danger')">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to create loads of these from an mysql query .
So using a for () loop I want to create buttons like these in a table's cell's , but first I need to figure out how to create the button.

So far I have

```
var btn = document.createElement("div");        
btn.className = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle";
btn.nodeType = "button";
btn.id = "testDropDownButton";
// btn.data-toggle = "dropdown";
```

but here I start getting errors and I am not sure if I am even heading in the right direction.

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the below jsfiddle-
https://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/xpvt214o/1025242/

```
    function createButton() {
      var div = document.createElement("div");

      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.className = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle";
      button.id = "dropdownMenuButton";
      button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
      button.setAttribute("aria-haspopup", "true");
      button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
      button.innerText="Dropdown button";

      div.append(button);
      div.className="dropdown";

      var linkDiv = document.createElement("div");
      linkDiv.className="dropdown-menu";
      linkDiv.setAttribute("aria-labelledby","dropdownMenuButton");

      var a = document.createElement("a")
      a.href="#"
      a.className="btn btn-success"
      a.id="testbtn"
      a.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript('ActionTxT1' , 'dropdownMenuButton', 'btn btn-success')")
      a.innerText="Action"

      linkDiv.append(a);
      div.append(linkDiv);

      $(".main-div").append(div);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ashique , The js fiddle isn't working.
I have tried copying the code and triggering it with a button press because window.onload didn't do anything with it.

It doesn't seem to work , even though it does look very different of what i was trying to do so thanks :-)

Comment: Hi Ashique,
I found the issue the $(".main-div").append(div); line wasn't appending the item to the page . I replaced it with document.body.append(div);

Comment: Hi Robert, Yes, you need to change the append function to the correct parent element for this to work. So this working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting errors when setting an attribute with a dash in it:

```
btn.data-toggle = "dropdown";
```

To set attributes, you have three options:

1) Use the `setAttribute()` method:

```
btn.setAttribute('data-toggle', "dropdown");
```

2) Set the attribute in the `dataset` property:.

```
btn.dataset['data-toggle'] = "dropdown";
```

3) Use camelCase notation:

```
btn.dataset.dataToggle = "dropdown";
```

When your element is built, add it an existing element using the `appendChild` method:

```
let div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.appendChild(btn);
```

To create the entire Bootstrap dropdown in JS, you'll be repeating this process for each child element.